# Querying Continuous Joystick Data

Tags: java, android, joystick, gamepad

I have a bluetooth gamepad connected to my Android device, and it is well connected and transmitting.
The *only* way to get data from the joystick appears to be from either `onGenericMotionEvent` or `dispatchGenericMotionEvent`
From the docs, on `onGenericMotionEvent`:

> Generic motion events describe joystick movements, mouse hovers, track pad touches, scroll wheel movements and other input events.

I have checked the source of my input, and verified that the source is correct, controller specs, etc.
However, the only input I get is a pure -1.0, 0.0, or 1.0 from my joystick, which is indeed inside the `MotionRange` specified. It never returns an in-between value.
Beyond that, I was concerned about batching (from the docs):

> For efficiency, motion events with ACTION_MOVE may batch together multiple movement samples within a single object.

Does this mean I can never have direct, immediate feedback on my joysticks? Even so, I checked the historical values, but `MotionEvent#getHistorySize` returned 0 for every analog input.
(On a side note, button events work fine)

Is this is a problem with the controller, batching, event handling, or something else? If it's not possible to avoid batching can I set up a separate thread to collect this information continuously?

For clarity, I'm using a Nintendo JoyCon (R) connected over bluetooth and API level 30.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further research, it appears that JoyCon joysticks simply transmit data as if they were D-pad buttons, in `AXIS_HAT_X` and `AXIS_HAT_Y` only.
I tried connecting other controllers and they functioned like expected.

There is definitely input delay, depending on the controller being used, but the data sent is relatively continuous. It appears to be that if the event system receives lots of changes in joystick data, it *might* plot 1 historical point, but most of the time it doesn't. [image: console log output]
So for most cases, batching shouldn't be an issue.

As for the Joy Cons, if it sounds like an internal limitation and not something I can get around.
I'm not sure if there's a way around this, but it explains the problems I was having.